# How to implement cubic interpolation in visual studio

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I created the polyline solution from a website tutorial using visual studio 2015 c#. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh868034.aspx

The xaml file is as follows:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFTestApplication.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:m="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF;assembly=Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF"
Width="1024" Height="768">
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <m:Map x:Name="myMap" CredentialsProvider="Insert_Your_Bing_Maps_Key" Center="47.740,-122.125" ZoomLevel="11">
        <m:MapPolyline Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="5" 
             Locations="47.6424,-122.3219 47.8424,-122.1747 47.5814,-122.1747 47.67856,-122.130994" 
             Opacity="0.7"/>
    </m:Map>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

The xaml.cs file is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF;

using Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Design;


namespace WPFTestApplication
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


                MapPolyline polyline = new MapPolyline();
                polyline.Stroke = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Blue);
                polyline.StrokeThickness = 5;
                polyline.Opacity = 0.7;
               polygon.Locations = new LocationCollection() { 
    new Location(47.6424,-122.3219), 
    new Location(47.8424,-122.1747), 
    new Location(47.5814,-122.1747)
    };


                myMap.Children.Add(polyline);



        }


    }
}
```

The output displays as follows:

The longitude,latitude points are connected by a polyline on the map. The polyline is a straight line.

I could like to use cubic/ spline interpolation to connect the longitude,latitude points to form a smooth curve. Is it possible to implement cubic/spline interpolation in this code? Are there built-in functions?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to use something diffrent from wpf see [DrawCurves](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/554h284b.aspx) which allows you to draw smooth curves.

If you need points on the spline for further calculations or want to stick with the MapPolyline a quick glance through google seems to bring up several project such as [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/560163/Csharp-Cubic-Spline-Interpolation). You first have to calculate the spline by yourself and then take an appropriate number of points and add them to your polyline object (to get the desired smothness)
The Class you use (MapPolyline) is more ore less for drawing Polygons, so a series of points connected by a straight line (as you are experiencing).